# JOIN LINES in BigSQL where PRODUCTs are the SAME

Tags: mysql, pivot, concatenation, unions, bigsql

I am having this sample table below

```
+---------+----------------------+
| PRODUCT | TYPE                 |
+---------+----------------------+
| WIN 10  | Home                 |
+---------+----------------------+
| WIN 10  | Pro                  |
+---------+----------------------+
| WIN 10  | Pro for Workstations |
+---------+----------------------+
| Linux   | Ubuntu               |
+---------+----------------------+
| Linux   | Red Hat              |
+---------+----------------------+
| Linux   | Fedora               |
+---------+----------------------+
```

I would like to change it (transpose) to have result like seen below using MySQL

```
+---------+-------------------------------+
| PRODUCT | TYPE                          |
+---------+-------------------------------+
| WIN 10  | Home,Pro,Pro for Workstations |
+---------+-------------------------------+
| Linux   | Ubuntu,Red Hat,Fedora         |
+---------+-------------------------------+
```

Could you please help me with that? I have tried everything I could using this forum and I am not able to get the result I need, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql You could use group_concat

```
select product, group_concat(type)
from my_table 
group by product
```

or  with order by

```
select product, group_concat(type order by type)
from my_table 
group by product
```

for BigSQL the equivalent function should be LISTAGG(type)

Comment: for BigSQL you could try with   LISTAGG(type)

Comment: I was finally able to concatenate the `TYPE` using `LISTAGG(DISTINCT TYPE,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TYPE)` but I can only do that for one `PRODUCT` at a time  when I specify it in `WHERE` clause. This siply does not work using `SELECT PRODUCT, LISTAGG(DISTINCT TYPE,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TYPE) from My_table`